# SQL replacing part of a url string

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, sql-like

I want to replace characters in a part of a url.

my url

```
www.website.com/images/some-image-in-the-folder.jpg
```

For example I will change all "`o`"s to "`1"` comes after the

```
www.website.com/images/ (always the same)
```

Result will be.

```
www.website.com/images/s1me-image-in-the-f1lder.jpg
```

MY data is like:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas nibh est, suscipit vel vestibulum in, bibendum eget erat. Sed condimentum auctor vulputate. Ut malesuada massa eget libero lobortis sodales. **img src="www.website.com/images/some-image-in-the-folder.jpg"** 
Sed eleifend lobortis nisl sit amet faucibus. Morbi eu nunc eget sapien pellentesque convallis eget at magna. Vivamus convallis sem at ante sodales vehicula. Morbi tempus tortor non leo fermentum scelerisque.

How do I do that?

MySQL 5.0.95
Apache/2.2.3
phpMyAdmin 3.5.7

Many thanks.
Im new at this :/

Comment: You need to state the database platform your using, is `www.website.com/images/` always the same?

Comment: In MySQL this might be what you're looking for http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: Which is your database?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, mysql

```
SET @url := 'www.website.com/images/some-image-in-the-folder.jpg';
SET @notreplace := 'www.website.com/images/';

SELECT CONCAT(@notreplace , REPLACE(MID(@url,LENGTH(@notreplace)+1,
LENGTH(@url)-LENGTH(@notreplace)),'o','1') )
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/11355)

SQL

```
DECLARE @url VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @notreplace VARCHAR(1000)

SET @url = 'www.website.com/images/some-image-in-the-folder.jpg'
SET @notreplace = 'www.website.com/images/'

SELECT @notreplace + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@url,LEN(@notreplace)+1,LEN(@url)-LEN(@notreplace)),'o','1')
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will allow you to search based on the value in the database (You won't need to supply a static string):

**First**: Use `substring_index` to get the section of the string that comes *after* `www.website.com/images/`

**Second**: Replace all instances of `o` returned from the first step with `1`

**Third**: Update the table with the final result

```
UPDATE table 
SET    yourcolumn = (SELECT Replace((SELECT 
                                   Substring_index((SELECT yourcolumn 
                                             FROM   yourtable), 
                                                'www.website.com/images/', 1 
                                                        )), 'o', '1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

*(This solution works most dynamic, by replacing every "o" after the last "/" - no matter what the URL is)*

The problem is, that just using `REPLACE()` would replace all occurrences of "o" - so you would have to split the string and then replace. Let's start with the split:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
  'www.website.com/images/some-image-in-the-folder.jpg',
  1,
  CHAR_LENGTH('www.website.com/images/some-image-in-the-folder.jpg') - LOCATE('/', REVERSE('www.website.com/images/some-image-in-the-folder.jpg')) + 1
);
```

This gives `www.website.com/images/`

Next, grab the right content and replace the string:

```
SELECT REPLACE(
  SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.website.com/images/some-image-in-the-folder.jpg', '/', -1),
  'o',
  '1'
);
```

This gives `'s1me-image-in-the-f1lder.jpg'

Finally, concat both:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING(
      'www.website.com/images/some-image-in-the-folder.jpg',
       1,
       CHAR_LENGTH('www.website.com/images/some-image-in-the-folder.jpg') - LOCATE('/', REVERSE('www.website.com/images/some-image-in-the-folder.jpg')) + 1
    )
  ,
    REPLACE(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.website.com/images/some-image-in-the-folder.jpg', '/', -1),
      'o',
      '1'
    )
  )
;
```

Voila: `www.website.com/images/s1me-image-in-the-f1lder.jpg` :)

**Notably, all used functions are bianry safe.**

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
update my_table set my_colum = replace(my_colum, "o", "1") 
WHERE post_content REGEXP "http://www\.website\.com/images/.*[o]+.*";
```